# Is the photoresistor, the MCP3008 or something else wrong/damaged?

Tags: sensor, mcp3008

I connected a photoresistor to an MCP3008 as described [here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#potentiometer) by replacing the potentiometer by a photoresistor (wiring should be correct). The LED-s work, I tested them separately and also on the board I want to use them. Also, there is light in my room.

Now when I execute the following program:

```
from gpiozero import LEDBarGraph, MCP3008
from signal import pause

graph = LEDBarGraph(5, 6, 13, 19, 26, pwm=True)
pot = MCP3008(channel=0)

graph.source = pot

print(pot.value)

pause()
```

I get values like 0.21446018563751834 but none of the LED's lights up.

On the other hand, if I execute this:

```
import spidev, time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)

def analog_read(channel):
    r = spi.xfer2([1, (8 + channel) << 4, 0])
    adc_out = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]
    return adc_out

while True:
    reading = analog_read(0)
    voltage = reading * 3.3 / 1024
    print("Reading=%d\tVoltage=%f" % (reading, voltage))
    time.sleep(1)
```

All I get is `Reading=0       Voltage=0.000000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Voltage was too low. Now I draw electricity from another socket and everything is fine.